# pipenv install command is failing while installing dependencies from local

Tags: python, dependencies, pipenv

I'm new to pipenv. I'm executing "pipenv install" command. Its creating virtual environment and installing the dependencies from the Pipfile.lock. But its failing while installing the dependency from local folder.

```
Command:- pipenv install
Pipfile:- my-api = {path = "./dependencies/my_api.zip"} 
Pipefile.lock:- "my-api": {
           "path": "./dependencies/my_api.zip"
       }
```

`Python version: 3.6.5`

I'm getting the below error:-

```
Supplied requirement is not installable: {0!r}".format(self.line)
17:17:30  pipenv.vendor.requirementslib.exceptions.RequirementError: Supplied requirement is not installable:
```

Can you please suggest the fix.

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Comment: You need to extract files from `my_api.zip`. The file format should be `.PipFile` and `.PipFile.lock`. You cannot pass zip for that.

Comment: Its issue with the special character in the absolute path. Pipenv is converting the relative path into absolute path while installing the custom/local dependencies. In my case the absolute path contains special character "%" so pipenv is not able to find the dependency. Is there any way to escape the special character in pipfile.